# How canI get EC2 pricing from AWS with Java code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get the EC2 price from AWS in my Java project.

Is there a way to retrieve this informations from AWS via code?

Answer (score 2):

1. Grab a JSON file with EC2 prices (https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json).
2. Parse the JSON file in Java. Here is an example from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

More on AWS Price List API: [Using the AWS Price List API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html)

Comment: The JSON file must be downloaded then parsed. Can i download it with code or not?

Comment: Of course, you can. There is `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and `java.io.InputStream` for that.

Comment: I need your suggestion, I am searching for another solution to get EC2 prices. I want to know the price of the 3 types of instances with their regions and if it possible with informations about CPU and RAM

Comment: Ec2 file and Rds json files are 1.2GB and 80mb, which doesnt fit on the mongodb for querying. please do note. live parsing may not be good one for any web apps. suggest if any other option!